# Wordpress AJAX and API calls printing filenames and permissions before the json response on VPS

Tags: ajax, wordpress, apache, api, vps

I am trying to move a Wordpress website from a shared hosting to a VPS.

All is going fine except AJAX and API calls.

Every AJAX call prints some files and folders permissions before the json output.

For example, if I call

```
{ROOT}/peepsoajax/chatajax.get_chats
```

instead of printing

```
{"has_errors":0,"success":1,"data":{"chats":[]}}
```

it prints this output (asterisks added manually):

```
drwxr-xr-x    2 cpk***t   cpk***t         4096 May  4 08:46 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 cpk***t   cpk***t         4096 May  4 08:46 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 cpk***t   cpk***t         4074 May  4 08:46 widgetlimitusers.php
drwxr-xr-x    2 cpk***t   cpk***t         4096 May  4 08:46 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 cpk***t   cpk***t         4096 May  4 08:46 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 cpk***t   cpk***t         4886 May  4 08:46 widgetfriends.php
-rw-r--r--    1 cpk***t   cpk***t        10042 May  4 08:46 widgetfriendsbirthday.php
-rw-r--r--    1 cpk***t   cpk***t         4117 May  4 08:46 widgetmutualfriends.php
drwxr-xr-x    2 cpk***t   cpk***t         4096 May  4 08:46 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 cpk***t   cpk***t         4096 May  4 08:46 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 cpk***t   cpk***t         3635 May  4 08:46 widgetcommunityphotos.php
-rw-r--r--    1 cpk***t   cpk***t         4068 May  4 08:46 widgetphotos.php
drwxr-xr-x    2 cpk***t   cpk***t         4096 May  4 08:46 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 cpk***t   cpk***t         4096 May  4 08:46 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 cpk***t   cpk***t         4872 May  4 08:46 widgetcommunityvideos.php
-rw-r--r--    1 cpk***t   cpk***t         5296 May  4 08:46 widgetvideos.php
{"has_errors":0,"success":1,"data":{"chats":[]}}
```

I have overwritten permalinks, changed urls in db, chmod every files and folder accordingly to 755 and 644, set chown www-data to the project, deactivated caches and security plugins... with no luck.

My .htaccess seems fine:

```
# BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[3.3.2]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL

<Files admin-ajax.php>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Satisfy any
</Files>

# BEGIN WordPress
# Le direttive (linee) tra `BEGIN WordPress` e `END WordPress` sono
# generate dinamicamente, e dovrebbero essere modificare solo con i filtri di WordPress.
# Ogni modifica alle direttive tra questi marcatori sarà sovrascritta.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

and my Virtual Host Directives seems good, too:

```
DocumentRoot {my_root}/public_html
ServerName {my_server.name}
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
<Directory "{my_root}/public_html">
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks 
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
Allow from all
</Directory>
ServerAlias {my_server.name}

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.my\.servername\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://test.my.servername.com/$1 [R=301,L]

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.my.servername.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.my.servername.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
IndexOptions SuppressDescription SuppressHTMLPreamble SuppressLastModified SuppressSize
Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks Includes IncludesNOEXEC Indexes MultiViews SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. While transferring files via wget ftp from the shared hosting to the VPS a new .listing file was created in every folder.

All it took was to launch

```
find . -name ".listing" -type f -delete
```

in the website root folder and the issue vanished.